# ParameterValues from MvxViewModelRequest are only available from first notification

Tags: android, mono, mvvmcross

Regarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402448/using-notifications-on-android-with-mvvmcross), I implemented a plugin for a message service similar like this:

```
        var activity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
        var context = activity.ApplicationContext;
        var request = MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
        request.ParameterValues = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "setId", setId.ToString() } };
        var translator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator>();
        var intent = translator.GetIntentFor(request);
        var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetContentIntent(pending);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)activity.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
```

The notification opens this ViewModel:

```
        public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
        {
           ...
           public void Init(int setId){...}
           ...
        }
```

The problem is, that myId in the ViewModel is always the Id from the first notification, even though the ParemeterValues is updated correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is standard Android behaviour.

Take a look at questions and blog posts like:

- [Android Status Bar Notifications - Intent getting the old extras on the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208547/android-status-bar-notifications-intent-getting-the-old-extras-on-the-second-t)
- [PendingIntent works correctly for the first notification but incorrectly for the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the)
- http://pilhuhn.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/pitfall-in-pendingintent-with-solution.html

I believe there are a few `Cancel` and `Update` flags you can pass to `PendingIntent.GetActivity` to workaround this - but I'm afraid I don't know which is ideal for your app.